# Does ReadyBoost help for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, readyboost

Is there any way that you can monitor if ReadyBoost actually has an impact on performance? I don't really experience much improvement.

Also can it be useful for Visual Studio anyway or would that never help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadyBoost is best noticable in start times of applications, given you don't use a SSD.

So, with ReadyBoost, Visual Studio should start faster once it's in the ReadyBoost cache.

Comment: Any way to figure out if it is in the ReadyBoost cache?

Comment: @Koen: Try to check what files are accessed with the [Resource Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/Video/ff710685).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly give you metrics on how much of a performance gain you're getting, but on Windows 7 there is a set of performance counters (perfmon.exe) called "ReadyBoost Cache" that will at least let you know when ReadyBoost is actually doing something. I notice lots of read activity in the cache when building a solution.

[image: ReadyBoost Cache Performance Counters Screenshot]